# Can't install tutorial content for javaee7 tutorial with updatetool

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, java-7, glassfish-4, java-ee-7

I downloaded the latest javaee7 tutorial and tried downloading the tutorial files with command `updatetool`. I did following steps:

- downloaded `glassfish4` zip file and unzipped it
- I set the `$AS_JAVA` variable equal to `$JAVA_HOME`. `JAVA_HOME` was correctly pointing to a valid oracle-7-jdk from earlier configuration.
- I then added parent `glassfish` and `glassfish` directory to `PATH`. When I do `which updatetool`, I get following: `/home/frrole/glassfish4/bin/updatetool`. So I guess all is fine. I'm also able to successfully fire glassfish server with `asadmin start-domain
- Now when I type `updatetool`, I receive following error:

> frrole@Frrole-NER1:/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle$ updatetool
>
> The software needed for this command (updatetool) is not installed.
>
> If you choose to install Update Tool, your system will be
>   automatically configured to periodically check for software updates.
>   If you would like to configure the tool to not check for updates, you
>   can override the default behavior via the tool's Preferences facility.
>
> When this tool interacts with package repositories, some system
>   information such as your system's IP address and operating system type
>   and version is sent to the repository server. For more information
>   please see:
>
> http://wikis.oracle.com/display/updatecenter/UsageMetricsUC2
>
> Once installation is complete you may re-run this command.
>
> Would you like to install Update Tool now (y/n): y
>
> Proxy: Using system proxy settings. Install image:
>   /home/frrole/glassfish4 Installing pkg packages. Downloading 2
>   packages. Downloading pkg (511 files, 6,237,937 bytes).
>
> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007ffb5b574920, pid=22316, tid=140717514012416
>
> JRE version: 7.0_21-b11
>    Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (23.21-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
>    Problematic frame:
>    C  [libdbus-1.so.3+0x26920]GConf Error: Configuration server couldn't be contacted: D-BUS error: Message has the same reply serial
>   as a currently-outstanding existing method call [thread
>   140717512959744 also had an error]   dbus_watch_handle+0x1b20
>
> Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
>
> An error report file with more information is saved as:
>    /home/frrole/glassfish4/hs_err_pid22316.log
>
> If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
>      http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
>    The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
>    See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
>    Aborted (core dumped)

I have no idea what is happening. Any help is much appreciated.

---

UPDATE:

Now, I'm getting the following error:

```
Would you like to install Update Tool now (y/n): y

Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Connection failed for URL http://pkg.oracle.com/javaeesdk/7/native/release/catalog/0: 500: Internal Server Error
    at com.sun.pkg.client.Image.checkRepositoryConnection(Image.java:1232)
    at com.sun.pkg.client.Catalog.refresh(Catalog.java:132)
    at com.sun.pkg.client.Image.refreshCatalogs(Image.java:1627)
    at com.sun.pkg.client.Client.main(Client.java:109)
Proxy: Using system proxy settings.
Input/output error: Connection failed for URL http://pkg.oracle.com/javaeesdk/7/release/catalog/0: 502: Proxy Error
```

Comment: Uh.. oh.. do you really need that update tool? Just carry on with the tutorial. This seems like a waste of time, imo.

Comment: @GGrec we use the Update Center to keep Tutorial updated from the SDK, and install it in the correct location so the examples build and run out-of-the-box.

Comment: I've not seen that error before. But see [this thread for a possible workaround for a similar situation](http://forums.connectopensource.org/Glassfish-Install-Fails-td7578664.html). In a nutshell: install the Java EE SDK using the Unix installer, not the GlassFish ZIP file.

Comment: Vaid , Have you solved this ?

Comment: You're getting a 500 error, which means either your request is invalid or their website is legitimately down.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the Java EE 7 SDK to get the Tutorial. The SDK installer will install and configure the Update Center and the Tutorial. The GlassFish 4.0 ZIP file isn't a supported configuration (but you can add the Tutorial to GlassFish 4.0 standalone using [these instructions](https://java.net/projects/javaeetutorial/pages/JavaEE7TutorialFAQ#Installing_the_Tutorial_from_a_GlassFish_4.0_Install).

In your case, it appears there's something wrong with the 32-bit compatibility libraries on 64-bit Linux when you run `pkg`.

Comment: Please read the update to the original post. Urgent Help needed.

Comment: At my company I am not allowed to install software. Therefore I am not able to get the tutorial source code using either the Update Tool or even the SDK install.  Thanks for making a simple task of being able to download some source files so difficult!

Comment: @jeff: if you can't install the SDK, which includes the Java EE server, it's hard to see how the example source code will do much good. I'm no longer at Oracle, but the point of the Tutorial bundle is to run the examples, which requires the ability to install software. You can read the Tutorial online, and you can also browse the source code repository at javaeetutorial.java.net. If you have Subversion installed, you can check out the repository as well. Best of luck.

Comment: @IanEvans: Thanks for getting back to me. BTW, I'm not blaming you for the difficulties :) I have Eclipse, JBOSS and JDK 7 installed on my machine. So the source code would be useful. After getting a username on java.net, I couldn't get svn to work with our proxy. I guess at least browsing file by file is better than nothing.

Comment: @jeff: Did you try the steps [here](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#proxy) for getting svn to work with a proxy server? Once you get the workspace, you'll still need to have Maven installed, and that requires downloading artifacts, etc, to compile the applications. I've heard that Eclipse supports Maven projects, so maybe you're covered, although we didn't ever test on Eclipse (just NetBeans and command-line mvn).

Comment: @IanEvans, I have maven within Eclipse.  OK, so, I got svn to work, didn't realize there were two urls, one with svn+ssh and the other without. Using just the http protocol, I was able to use a unix box I have access to. But now trying to move all the files from that server to my windowspc/eclipse.  I have to read up on svn, because I don't want to check out all 100,000+ files, just the latest.  The issue now is transfering almost a gig over is having some hicups.

Comment: @jeff Yeah, just check out the trunk, or the latest branch.

Comment: ASFAK JBOSS doesn'T support the Java EE 7 at the moment, neither in the EAP nor in the AS Edition.

Comment: @Peter: WildFly 8 is the EE 7 version of JBoss, and a release candidate has apparently passed the EE 7 TCK. So an EE 7 version is imminent.

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked and both http://pkg.oracle.com/javaeesdk/6/release/ as well as http://pkg.oracle.com/javaeesdk/7/release/ return HTTP 503 Service Unavailable. So, it isn't possible to perform any updates anyway. However, the glassfish/doc directory should contain tutorial source code already, and one may skip update step.